# shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote the following script to create a [taylor diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_diagram) using [SkillMetrics](https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics), an open-source Python library for calculating model predictions against observations.

The script I wrote was:

```
import skill_metrics as sm 

# Arrange datasets in array
stats1 = np.array([ref,m1])
stats2 = np.array([ref,m2])
stats3 = np.array([ref,m3])

# calculating statistics
taylor_stats1 = sm.taylor_statistics(stats1[0],stats1[1])
taylor_stats2 = sm.taylor_statistics(stats2[0],stats2[1])
taylor_stats3 = sm.taylor_statistics(stats3[0],stats3[1])

# Store statistics in arrays
sdev = np.array([taylor_stats1['sdev'][0], taylor_stats1['sdev'][1],
                 taylor_stats2['sdev'][1], taylor_stats3['sdev'][1]])
crmsd = np.array([taylor_stats1['crmsd'][0], taylor_stats1['crmsd'][1],
                  taylor_stats2['crmsd'][1], taylor_stats3['crmsd'][1]])
ccoef = np.array([taylor_stats1['ccoef'][0], taylor_stats1['ccoef'][1],
                  taylor_stats2['ccoef'][1], taylor_stats3['ccoef'][1]])
```

which produces:

```
sdev = array([ 0.02556107,  0.06264893,  0.06264893,  0.06264893])

crmsd = array([ 0.        ,  0.04918169,  0.04824091,  0.05082715])
ccoef = array([ 1.        ,  0.67423927,  0.68388202,  0.64162831])
```

I then ran the following to create the taylor diagram:

```
sm.taylor_diagram(sdev,crmsd,ccoef)
```

However, I then received this error:

```
shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a python 2 issue. Seems the `skill_metrics package` is intended to be used only with python 3. The error comes from the source of the package, you are not doing anything wrong here.

In python3 [the line in question](https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics/blob/07852bdddd4a797887f1ece3668f31ea0a6154e2/skill_metrics/overlay_taylor_diagram_circles.py#L52) should only throw a warning, not an error.

The only chance you have is probably to either use python 3 or to dive into the source code.

- Locate the file `site-packages\skill_metrics\overlay_taylor_diagram_circles.py`
- inside this file, find the lines (should be around line 50)

  ```
  # now really force points on x/y axes to lie on them exactly
  inds = range(0,len(th),(len(th)-1) // 4)
  xunit[inds[1:3:2]] = np.zeros(2)
  yunit[inds[0:4:2]] = np.zeros(3)
  ```
- replace them with

  ```
  inds = range(0,len(th),(len(th)-1) // 4)
  xunit[74] = 0
  yunit[148] = 0
  ```

Comment: Hello @ImportanceOfBeingErnes thank you for detail explanation. I checked my python version and I have python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit), Now I am trying to find source file and let you know.

Comment: Thank you verymuch now it works by changing source code :)