# ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote a simple code to form taylor digram using skillmetrics package. I used python version Python 2.7.12.The code is as follows:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import skill_metrics as sm
fire=pd.read_csv('fire.csv')
PMfire = zip(fire['Date'],fire['PM_fire'],fire['Embassy_PM'])
#taylor_stats1 = sm.taylor_statistics('PM_fire','Embassy_PM','Date')
o= {"Data":fire['Embassy_PM'],'Date':fire['Date']}# form date and and embassy datas
p= {"Data":fire['PM_fire'],'Date':fire['Date']}# form  dictionary containg pm_fire and date
# Calculate statistics for Taylor diagram
    # The first array element corresponds to the reference series 
    # for the while the second is that for the predicted series.
taylor_stats1 = sm.taylor_statistics(p,o,'Data')
sdev = np.array([taylor_stats1['sdev'][0]])# Calculate standard deviation
crmsd = np.array([taylor_stats1['crmsd'][0]])#Calculate root mean square difference
ccoef = np.array([taylor_stats1['ccoef'][0]])# Calculate correlation coefficient
sm.taylor_diagram(sdev,crmsd,ccoef)#form taylor digram
plt.savefig('taylor.png')
plt.show()
```

At first I was getting error as in the link [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492556/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-to-rgb/47492708?noredirect=1#comment81940887_47492708). But, now I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-edf3b67792d8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/mala/Downloads/F/taylor_plot.py', wdir='/home/mala/Downloads/F')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/mala/Downloads/F/taylor_plot.py", line 24, in <module>
    sm.taylor_diagram(sdev,crmsd,ccoef)#form taylor digram

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skill_metrics/taylor_diagram.py", line 91, in taylor_diagram
    overlay_taylor_diagram_circles(axes,cax,option)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skill_metrics/overlay_taylor_diagram_circles.py", line 51, in overlay_taylor_diagram_circles
    xunit[inds[1:3:2]] = np.zeros(2)

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)
```

I also tried [shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890371/shape-mismatch-value-array-of-shape-2-could-not-be-broadcast-to-indexing-res). Then tried python3.5.2. But, it gives me same error.

Comment: This looks like a straight up bug in the `skill_metrics` package.

Comment: @ngoldbaum What can be done to remove this bug?

Comment: Not sure offhand, I have no idea what this package is doing. If you didn't write it yourself, I'd try reporting an issue. If you did write `skill_metrics` then you need to figure out why it's trying to broadcast a two-element array into a single value in another array.

Comment: I'd review the docs of `taylor_diagram` and make sure the 3 arguments have the correct shape(s).